# Like button doesn´t show up

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This is driving me crazy.
I got the code from the fb own tool at:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

Also got the meta key needed.

```
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="100002771809798"/>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frecept.se%2Fcontent%2Fatt-gora-honungskaka-med-mandel

Gives me 206 but it shouldnt be enough to hide the button should it?

Heres an example page(Scroll down below the article).
http://recept.se/content/att-gora-honungskaka-med-mandel

Anyone able to clear this out for me?

Comment: You have only embedded the JS SDK, but you have not put any XFBML element into your HTML at the place where you want the like button to be rendered …

Comment: Ok, where do i find an example of this element?

Comment: On the very page where you grabbed the rest of the code from …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working just by copying the code from the plugins/like page on facebook.

You probably forgot to include this code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

It says everything right here: 
[Image](http://www.mediafire.com/?wa2712kbu1948a1)

Comment: Np, glad that's all you were missing

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there should only be one `<div id="fb-root"></div>` on any given page, regardless of the amount of `<div id="fb-like...></div>` tags. This could be many things, but it may be because there is more than one tag with the ID `fb-root`. After all, it appears on each individual article, but not on the main blogroll.